# How to fix problems with different keyboard layouts in iChat screen sharing?

Tags: ichat, screen-sharing, keyboard

My Mac has a QWERTY keyboard. When someone with a Mac with an AZERTY keyboard shared their screen with me in iChat, I had to pretend I was typing on an AZERTY keyboard to make any text I was typing come out right on the shared screen. Is this a known bug? Is there a way to fix it? (I didn't try, but I assume I could switch the layout to QWERTY on the shared Mac in System Preferences, but then we'd have to constantly switch back-and-forth as the other person needs to type something on the AZERTY keyboard. So I'm wondering whether there's a better solution.)

Comment: That's really weird...

Comment: Yes it's weird. But it happens every time this person shares their screen with me. I haven't tried yet whether the problem also occurs when others with a non-QWERTY layout share their screen with me.

Comment: I wonder, if you share your QWERTY keyboard with an AZERTY user, do they need to use QWERTY or AZERTY?